# Getting a Key Error on page reload

Tags: python, flask

So I'm having a problem in that anytime I refresh the page I am getting a Key Error, it works perfectly the first time the page is reloaded but fails the second time.

Here's the rough structure:

```
def myAPICall()

    response = myclient.REST(URL)

    data = response.json()

    return data


@app.route('/index', methods=['GET'])
def passData():
    data = myAPICall()

    for x in data:
        make some changes to the dictionary

    return (render_template('index.html', data=data))
```

Upon refresh of my page, I get a keyerror on one of the keys within the 'data' dictionary.

If I restart the server it will work correctly, but the next time I refresh the KeyError will appear again.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for days.

Error message:

```
[ d2['id'] for d2 in data if d2['asset_id'] == d1['id'] ]

KeyError: 'id'
```

Comment: can you provide further details on your apicall function and the error stack please?

Answer (score 0):

From your error message, I'm assuming `data` contains list of objects. Now, not all of these objects have key `id`. So, instead of looking up directly in `d1` or `d2`, use `d2.get('id', 'alternate_default_value')`.

Now, if you want to know why there are missing keys, you need to provide more details, i.e. what type of data you are fetching etc.